# how to pass in list variable in url string witout "[ ] '" in python

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I need to format a url string for using with urllib: 
the url string I want to get are as:

```
http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

if I use

```
namelist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
url = 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name={namelist}'.format(namelist=namelist}
```

then I get:

```
http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
```

so how should I format an url string by passing in a string list wihout "[]'"?

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer, if your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 4):

Your first option is what the other answers suggest: to create your comma-separated list yourself, like so:

```
import urllib.parse
query_string = 'name=' + ','.join(namelist)
url = 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?{query_string}'.format(query_string=query_string)
# url == 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=A,B,C,D,E,F,G'
```

This fits what you asked for, however it has some limitations: first, if one of your names has a comma, it will not be correctly escaped.
Second, the commas in your list, and other characters in `namelist` won't be properly encoded for the URL.

Your second option, a more robust version of the previous one, is to encode your list, like so:

```
import urllib.parse
query_params = {'name': ','.join(namelist)}
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_params)
url = 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?{query_string}'.format(query_string=query_string)
# url == 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=A%2CB%2CC%2CD%2CE%2CF%2CG'
```

This will properly escape the characters for URL usage, but you are still left with the manual assembling and parsing of the query string.

There is a third option, which I would suggest: use the standard way of passing a list in the query string, which is to repeat the key.

```
import urllib.parse
query_params = {'name': namelist}
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_params, doseq=True)
url = 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?{query_string}'.format(query_string=query_string)
# url == 'http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=A&name=B&name=C&name=D&name=E&name=F&name=G'
```

This last option, a bit more verbose, is more robust though, as the URL parser will return a list you don't need to parse.
Additionally, if there is a comma in one of your names, it will be automatically escaped.

Check out the difference between the three options:

```
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('name=A,B,C,D,E,F,G')
{'name': ['A,B,C,D,E,F,G']}
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('name=A%2CB%2CC%2CD%2CE%2CF%2CG')
{'name': ['A,B,C,D,E,F,G']}
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs('name=A&name=B&name=C&name=D&name=E&name=F&name=G')
{'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
```

Last one will be easier to work with!

Answer (score 2):

Join the list into a string with...

`'[insert seperator here]'.join(namelist)`

so in your case

`','.join(namelist)`
this produces 'A,B,C,D,E,F'...

Then you can use your initial method with the `.format()`

Answer (score 1):

```
.format(namelist=",".join(namelist))
```

will work, using "," between list entries

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: you can also use the nice [F-string feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) of Python 3. It's a lot prettier than `.format()` imo, and reminds you of other programming languages that allow variable interpolation.

```
namelist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
url = f"http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name={','.join(namelist)}"

print(url)
# http://localhost:8086/service/records/names?name=A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```